# Rails wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) @post.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have the following controller :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end


    private 
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
        end


end
```

ANd my model is

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

My new.html.erb page is

```
<h1> New post </h1>
<%= form_for :post, url:posts_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %> <br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>

    <p> 
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>

    <% end %>
```

routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :posts
 root "posts#index"
end
```

I keep getting this error : 
ArgumentError in PostsController#create
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

what did I do wrong here ?

Comment: Add server error logs and give a glimps of your model.

Comment: Can you also show your view for new action

Comment: I added the view but the error is controller related.

Comment: add model also please, including validations

Comment: Please show your routes also :)

Comment: Code above looks perfectly fine. @Rubyrider's right, logs would be more helpful.